# Error 404 when accessing a file via a Service Account

Tags: php, excel, google-api, google-oauth

I have to read an excel file on google drive. I need to connect automatically to google drive without prompt any form... a bot must read document... I have this code:

```
$service_account_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/key-85ac95ab1e62.json';
$spreadsheet_id = 'the_id_inside_the_url_of_the_file';

$spreadsheet_range = 'Sheet1!A1:A1';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $service_account_file);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheet_id, $spreadsheet_range);
var_dump($result->getValues());
```

Something goes wrong... I explain how I generated the `key-*.json` file:

On `Google Console Developer` i clicked on Service Account, then i created a new one and downloaded the json.. this json is the `key-*.json` file. I have added this file in my project (as you can see on first row)... Here i copied the `Account Service Id`that I will use later...

Now I explain how I get the `spreadheet_id`... I went on my google drive, right click on the file and I shared it with the `Account Service Id` (copied before) and an url has been generated... if I copy and past the url in the browser everything works but not in the project... i take the spreadsheet_id from url

this is the error I receive :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND
  }
}
```

What's wrong? the file exists and i cann see it in the browser using the same url I use in the php file... so I think it is a connection or login problem...

any idea?

Comment: you need a service account on the Google API, and use that account to connect. The API docs explain it all, with examples.

Comment: I have a service account... and I am reading the docs.... The code I pasted on post is from docs... but it is not what  I need

Comment: if you have a service account, then why is it asking for user credentials? Where did you find this code sample exactly?

Comment: mmm so, you mean something else perhaps... I am using this doc: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: yeah the first part of that examples describes using an OAuth flow which requires user credentials. This article https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount has more info on service accounts (in general, it's not specific to the Sheets API). And here's a snippet I found which shows how to read from a spreadsheet using a service account (I've no idea if it works, but it seems to be in the right direction): https://github.com/juampynr/google-spreadsheet-reader . I'm sure you can use that as a basis to then expand it to creating and editing them too

Comment: ok I follow this guide... and however, i di not have a service account.. If I still need help I update the post... thnk you

Comment: I updated the post...

Comment: "the same url I use in the php file." This could be the problem. The URL used for the UI is probably not the URL you use to call the API, since one returns HTML and one returns data. They are almost certainly different endpoints with different functionality. Again consult the docs for how you should do it. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get . Note that the PHP client library will construct most of the URL for you - you just need to supply the spreadsheet ID. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts explains how to discover the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual problem with Service Accounts. Refer to any of these https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=404+service+account

In simple terms a Service Account is **NOT** the same as the Google Account that you used to create it. Either don't use Service Accounts, or share the file from its own account to the Service Account to give it access.